# Cefsharp / Javascript issue focusing on input field

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

I'm not sure if this is a `cefsharp` issue or just `Javascript` one, but when testing filling in a form on a test site i'm coming across this:

[image: issue]

When `cefsharp` is filling in the fields, it's placing the values over the text instead of inside the input field.

```
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = 'test@test.com';
```

So after reading (i'm sure it's a focus issue) i tried:

```
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].focus();
```

Which should have worked by all accounts, but it never showed any difference from the image above.

I even tried:

```
document.querySelector("//*[@id="email"]").click();
```

The xpath to the field, still no difference.

Is it some how needing set from a `cefsharp` point of view? any tips in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Could you please include the HTML definition of the form?

Comment: Load the same web page in Chrome,  open DevTools and run your script,  do you get the same result? I expect your input fields have validation that is looking for mouse/key focus events which your JavaScript doesn't trigger.